# Integration of $x^2 e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate $x^2 e^x$? I have tried it for a long time and attempted so many ways but I still can't get any idea on how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Integration by parts should do.

Comment: With respect to what variable?

Comment: The integral has the form $$(x^2+a_1x+a_0)e^x+C$$
for a convenient choice of constants $a_1$ and $a_0$. You can indeed find the integral using integration by parts.

Comment: @pyrazolam respect to x

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try integration by parts

$ \int{x^2e^xdx} $

Let $ u = x^2 $, $ v = e^x $
Then $ du = 2xdx $, $dv = e^xdx $

$ \int{x^2vdx} = \int{udv} = uv - \int{vdu} = x^2e^x - \int{2xe^xdx}$

Note that we have reduced the power of $ x $ from $ x^2 $ to $ x $, so it looks like our approach worked, let's just do it one more time.

Let $ p = x $, $ q = e^x $
Then $ dp = dx $, $ dq = e^xdx $

$ \int{x^2vdx} = x^2e^x - \int{2xe^xdx} = x^2e^2 - 2\int{pdq} = x^2e^2 - 2(pq - \int{qdp}) = x^2e^x - 2(xe^x - \int{e^xdx}) = x^2e^x - 2(xe^x - e^x) = x^2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x $

It is always good to double check, so let's do that

$ (x^2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x)' = 2xe^x + x^2e^x - 2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x = x^2e^x$

QED $ \blacksquare $

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use integration by parts here's a different approach.

\begin{align*}
\int x^2e^{ax}\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial a^2}e^{ax}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial a^2}\int e^{ax}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial a^2}\frac{e^{ax}}{a} \\
\end{align*}

Now take the derivative and plug in $a=1$.

Comment: This tricked is called Feymann. Of course, named after the physicist Richard Feymann

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: @AndrewAu His name is "Richard Feynman," and not "Richard Feymann."

Comment: @GPhys I just wanted to ask how did the $$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial a^2}$$ find it's way out of that integral?

Comment: @Nikunj That is the 'trick'. You can [show it's valid if used properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: Got it, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

With integration by parts $\int u'v = uv - \int uv'$ applied twice:

$$\int x^2e^x dx = x^2e^x -\int 2xe^x dx = x^2e^x - 2xe^x + 2e^x +C = e^x(x^2 - 2x +2) +C$$

Answer (score 1):

When you have done a few of these integrals, you'll notice a pattern: $\int xe^x\,dx$ is of the form $(x-1)e^x$, $\int x^2e^x\,dx$ is of the form $(x^2-2x+2)e^x$ (plus the constant, of course).

Let's get bold and state that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then
$$
\int p(x)e^x\,dx = q(x)e^x + C
$$
where $q(x)$ is another polynomial of degree $n$.

The trick is integration by parts:
$$
\int p(x)e^x\,dx=p(x)e^x-\int p'(x)e^x\,dx
$$
Since $p'(x)$ has degree $n-1$, induction allows to conclude. The base step is obvious: if $p(x)$ has degree $0$, the statement is just
$$
\int ae^x\,dx=ae^x+C
$$

Now you know that
$$
\int x^2e^x\,dx=(ax^2+bx+c)e^x+C
$$
and it's just a matter of differentiating the right-hand side:
$$
(2ax+b)e^x+(ax^2+bx+c)e^x=x^2e^x
$$
gives
$$
\begin{cases}
a=1\\
2a+b=0\\
b+c=0
\end{cases}
$$
so $b=-2$ and $c=2$.

Similarly,
$$
\int (x^2+3x-1)e^x\,dx=(ax^2+bx+c)e^x+C
$$
and the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
a=1\\
2a+b=3\\
b+c=-1
\end{cases}
$$
so $b=1$ and $c=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** integrating by parts

$$\int x^n e^x dx = x^n e^x - \int nx^{n-1} e^x dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the tabular method:

We pick something for $u$ that will differentiate to $0$ after multiple differentiations. So pick $u = x^2$ and pick $dv = e^x\,dx$. So, $$\begin{matrix} & u & dv\\\hline + & x^2 & \int e^x\,dx = e^x\\- & 2x & \int e^x\,dx = e^x\\+ &2 & \int e^x\,dx = e^x\\ - &0 & \int e^x\,dx = e^x.\end{matrix}$$ Draw diagonals starting from the $+$ on the first line down to the next line. Multiply these terms together. Repeat this for each line. So our solution becomes $$\int x^2e^x\,dx= x^2e^x-2xe^x+2e^x + C$$